# Objective-C: Cast super instance variable in subclass?

Tags: objective-c, inheritance, casting, instance-variables, ivar

In Objective-C, in the definition of a subclass (perhaps in the interface file), is it possible to cast an instance variable (ivar) that's inherited from the super class?

I want to do this because I've defined the superclass's ivar as `NSObject *session`, and I want to cast the subclasse's ivar to `Facebook *session`, so that I don't have to cast it every time I'm sending it a message that `Facebook` instances respond to but `NSObject` instances don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to change the type of a superclass interface variable, one thing you could do is to add a getter method, such as

```
- (Facebook *) getSession {

   return (Facebook *)[self session];

}
```

Comment: I believe this is why `init` methods are dynamically typed (they are declared to return `id`).

Comment: Yeah, I declared a local variable, e.g., `Facebook *fbSession = (Facebook *)self.session`, but your approach is more extensible. Thanks!